# How can I put a placeholder in a struts2 textfield tag?

Tags: java, html, struts2, placeholder

I'm using struts2 tags and want to put a placeholder in a `<s:textfield>` tag like this:

```
<s:set name="email" value="getText('email')" />
...

<s:form action="Login">
    <s:textfield key="email" theme="simple" placeholder="%{email}" 
         cssClass="span3"/>
    ...
</s:form>
```

`email` is defined in `global.properties` as "Correo electrónico" .

My problem is that when I see the jsp page, instead of seeing the value of `email` I see `%{email}`.

I read that it was a bug of Struts2 solved in version 2.3.1 here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3644, but I'm using Struts2 2.3.4 and I keep having the same problem.

Anyone knows any solution to this problem or any other way for putting the placeholder in the textfield?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
<s:textfield name="user.email" placeholder="%{getText('settings.email')}" />
```

I needed up update both my Struts 2 *and* OGNL jars. My OGNL jar is `ognl-3.0.5.jar`.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow, I promise.

Comment: No problem! Just trying to help

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `#` prefix for variables created in the stack namespace but not pushed:

```
<s:textfield placeholder="%{#email}" ... etc ... />
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. The placeholder prints `%{#email}`. It doesn't evaluate the expression :(

Comment: @DaveNewton - How about putting placeholders on autocompleters?