# showing additional info form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this [web app](http://www.chercherecole.com) in which users have to fill a form. To help them to understand each field of the form, I was wondering which would be the best way to show fields' descriptions. I was thinking in displaying a bubble with the description of the field when the user clicks the field or, simpler, displaying a tooltip??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doubling up on your question marks still doesn't make it a good question. What part do you need help with?

Comment: If you want something simple, you could use the HTML placeholder attribute, or simply reveal a hint beneath (or next to) the field of interest when that field is in focus. If you want something more robust, you could use qTip2 (http://qtip2.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5's placeholder attribute.  The use is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name...">
```

This will place placeholder text inside of the textbox.  Once a user begins typing, the text is automatically cleared from the box.

Comment: Good answer, though I would also recommend using a placeholder shim (such as [this jQuery one](https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim)) for non-compliant browsers

Comment: The more backwards compatibility, the better!  Good addition, though I'm not sure why their documentation shows it included in the header, as opposed to just before the closing body tag.  +1 for the compatibility thought though, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to indicate I'm using Struts 2 s:textfield and it doesn't allow placeholder attribute

Comment: That can be found in a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155028/how-can-i-put-a-placeholder-in-a-struts2-textfield-tag).